# compare two years data month wise in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one table in mysql like this

```
   Date       Cases Type
   2015-12-01     1 A
   2015-12-10     2 B
   2015-12-25     1 A
   2015-12-11     1 B
   2015-11-14     2 B
   2015-11-12     2 B
   2015-11-13     2 B
   2015-11-14     2 B
   2015-11-14     2 B
   2015-10-15     2 B
   2015-10-16     2 B
   2015-10-17     2 A
   2015-10-18     2 A
   2015-10-19     2 B
   2015-09-20     2 A
   2015-09-21     2 B
   2015-09-22     2 A
   2015-09-23     2 B
   2015-09-24     2 A
   2015-08-25     2 B
   2015-08-26     2 B
   2015-08-27     2 A
   2015-08-28     2 B
   2015-08-29     2 B
   2015-08-30     2 A
   2015-07-01     2 B
   2015-07-02     2 A
   2015-07-03     2 B
   2015-07-04     2 B
   2015-07-05     2 A
   2015-07-06     2 B
   2015-07-07     2 B
   2015-07-08     2 A
   2015-06-09     2 B
   2015-06-10     2 A
   2015-06-11     2 B
   2015-06-12     2 B
   2015-05-13     2 A
   2015-05-14     2 B
   2015-04-15     2 B
   2015-04-16     2 A
   2015-04-15     2 B
   2015-03-16     2 B
   2015-03-15     2 A
   2015-03-16     2 B
   2015-03-15     2 B
   2015-02-16     2 A
   2015-02-15     2 B
   2015-02-16     2 A
   2015-01-16     2 B
   2015-01-15     2 A
   2015-01-16     2 B
   2014-12-25     1 B
   2014-12-11     1 A
   2014-11-14     2 A
   2014-11-12     2 A
   2014-11-13     2 A
   2014-11-14     2 A
   2014-10-15     2 A
   2014-10-16     2 A
   2014-10-17     2 B
   2014-10-18     2 B
   2014-10-19     2 A
   2014-09-20     2 B
   2014-09-21     2 A
   2014-09-22     2 B
   2014-09-23     2 A
   2014-09-24     2 B
   2014-08-25     2 A
   2014-08-26     2 A
   2014-08-27     2 B
   2014-08-28     2 A
   2014-08-29     2 A
   2014-08-30     2 B
   2014-07-01     2 A
   2014-07-02     2 B
   2014-07-03     2 A
   2014-07-04     2 A
   2014-07-05     2 B
   2014-07-06     2 A
   2014-07-07     2 A
   2014-07-08     2 B
   2014-06-09     2 A
   2014-06-10     2 B
   2014-06-11     2 A
   2014-06-12     2 A
   2014-05-13     2 B
   2014-05-14     2 A
   2014-04-15     2 A
   2014-04-16     2 B
   2014-04-15     2 A
   2014-03-16     2 A
   2014-03-15     2 B
   2014-03-16     2 A
   2014-03-15     2 A
   2014-02-16     2 B
   2014-02-15     2 A
   2014-02-16     2 B
   2014-01-16     2 A
   2014-01-15     2 B
   2014-01-16     2 A
```

And I want output like this

```
Month   2015(cases)     2014(cases)
Jan         6               6
Feb         6               6 
 |
 |
Dec         5               2
```

I have tried upto some extent like this

```
SELECT SUM(Cases), MONTHNAME(Date), 2015 as YEAR FROM cases
                        WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2015 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Date)
            UNION ALL        
               SELECT SUM(Cases), MONTHNAME(Date), 2014 as YEAR FROM cases
                        WHERE YEAR(Date) = 2014 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Date)
```

And trying to use this as a table in from clause. But got stuck in search of light to solve ahead.

Any suggestion?

Comment: @Strawberry, dates are already stored as date data type.

Comment: Issues such as this are generally best handled in the presentation layer/application level code, if that's available.

Comment: @Strawberry, May I know what do you mean by "presentation layer/application level code" ?  Is that not possible by sql code ?

Comment: It's possible. But it tends to be rather inflexible/unscalable. Better to use application code (e.g. PHP, if that's available) to process the result. For instance, what would happen if there were no cases for March 2014?

Comment: @Strawberry, In that case for march field under 2014 it would be null or 0. Can you help me to write sql code of above given scenario ?

Comment: It's just too tedious to do it your way. The query I'd use would be something like `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m') ym,SUM(cases) total_cases FROM my_table GROUP BY ym ORDER BY YEAR(date) DESC,MONTH(date);` The rest I'd do in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You appear CLOSE in your attempted solution... try

```
SELECT 
      MONTHNAME(Date) as ShowMonth,
      COALESCE( SUM( case when year( Date ) = 2015 then cases else 0 end ), 0 ) as Cases2015,
      COALESCE( SUM( case when year( Date ) = 2014 then cases else 0 end ), 0 ) as Cases2014
   from
      ( select
              Month( @fakeDate ) as MonthNumber,
              @fakeDate := DATE_ADD( @fakeDate, INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
           from 
              ( select @fakeDate := '2014-01-01' ) sqlvars,
              cases
           limit 12 ) allMonths
         JOIN Cases
            on allMonths.MonthNumber = Month( cases.Date )
   where
      Year( Date ) in ( 2014, 2015 )
   group by
      MONTHNAME(Date) 
   order by
      MONTH( Date )
```

This will have the months ordered by their numeric representation, but SHOW the NAME.  The columns will represent the cases per respective year.

The inner query will create a fake table of just dates for a 12 month period starting with Jan 1, 2014 thus the LIMIT 12 will take it 12 months until Dec, 2014.  Now we have all POSSIBLE MONTHS (12 records) and is joined to the cases table on the actual data by same month.  So now you should get all 12 months REGARDLESS of having a given month within the data stream.

To fix those that have NO values, I have changed the query to COALESCE() to prevent "NULL" as a returned value. (unless you are ok to show null in your output).

I also put year 2015 data in the second vs third column.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this help !! :)

Comment: @Kate, You are welcome.  Also, check out Help -> Tour for site etiquette... welcome to the Stack.

Comment: @Kate You still have the problem of missing months though.

Comment: @Kate, I revised the query to build a dynamic MONTHs listing table so ALL months will be visible regardless of no such activity for a given month.

Comment: @Strawberry, revised to include dynamically built month list table.  Not difficult at all.

Comment: Not difficult. Just tedious, inflexible and scales poorly.